# GitLab Omnibus configuration for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, gitlab

I'm trying to install `gitlab_6.8.1-omnibus.4-1_amd64.deb` on my development Debian 7 (Wheezy) machine where Postgres 9.1 is already installed.

When I run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` I catch an error:

```
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[migrate database]'
    ======================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed  
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake db:migrate ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
rake aborted!
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "gitlab"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "gitlab"
```

I created both users `git` and `gitlab` (with passwords `git` and `gitlab`) in Postgres but it didn't help.

`/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log` is full of authentication errors:

```
2014-05-10 14:51:30 MSK FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "gitlab"
```

How can I configure PostgreSQL options to install GitLab Omnibus?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved the problem with my existing PostgreSQL instance.

1. Add to `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

   ```
   # Disable the built-in Postgres
   postgresql['enable'] = false

   gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
   gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'unicode'
   # Create database manually and place its name here.
   gitlab_rails['db_database'] = 'gitlabhq_production'
   gitlab_rails['db_host'] = '127.0.0.1'
   gitlab_rails['db_port'] = '5432'
   gitlab_rails['db_username'] = 'git' # Database owner.
   gitlab_rails['db_password'] = 'git' # Database owner's password.
   ```
2. Run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.
3. Import default data:

   ```
   sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:setup
   ```

Alternative variant is to set custom port for build-in PostgreSQL:

```
    postgresql['enable'] = true
    postgresql['port'] = 5433
```

This will run separate PostgreSQL instance on specified port.

Comment: I have followed your solution. Gitlab reconfigure is run smoothly. But the setup didn't goes well. It related to Pgsql fail to authenticate gilab user trough ident method. Do you have any advice for me?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by renaming the postgres directory that already existed in the /var/opt/gitlab directory:

```
[root@awsafinva1184:/var/opt/gitlab]#  ls -l 
total 52
drwx------ 2 git          root       4096 Dec  8 09:52 backups
-rw------- 1 root         root         38 Dec  8 09:52 bootstrapped
drwx------ 4 git          root       4096 Feb 20  2015 git-data
drwxr-xr-x 3 git          root       4096 Dec  8 09:52 gitlab-ci
drwxr-xr-x 8 git          root       4096 Dec  8 10:29 gitlab-rails
drwx------ 2 git          root       4096 Dec  8 10:29 gitlab-shell
drwxr-x--- 2 git          gitlab-www 4096 Dec  8 09:53 gitlab-workhorse
drwx------ 3 root         root       4096 Dec  8 10:02 logrotate
drwxr-x--- 8 root         gitlab-www 4096 Dec  8 10:06 nginx
drwxr-xr-x 3 gitlab-psql  root       4096 Dec  8 10:24 postgresql.org
drwxr-x--- 2 gitlab-redis git        4096 Dec  8 10:29 redis
```

Then I just reran the `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` command which then ran successfully.

Comment: Worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use：

cat >> /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb << "EOF"

postgresql['enable'] = true

postgresql['port'] = 5432

postgresql['listen_address'] = "*"

postgresql['md5_auth_cidr_addresses'] = ['127.0.0.1/32','0.0.0.0/0','::1/128']

postgresql['trust_auth_cidr_addresses'] = ['127.0.0.1/32','::1/128']

EOF

gitlab-ctl reconfigure

gitlab-ctl restart